# Laravel runtime error : Invalid Request ( An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using a laravel application with mysql as backend.
When running the laravel application it shows the following message

**Invalid Request ( An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)**

Its working properly in last few months..but now it shows this message and the application stops the execution
Also, when i tried to restart the application , it works fine for sometime and then repeat the same.

Can anyone help me to figure out this ..?

Comment: This is the issue if you are working with third party application.

Comment: How can i resolve this ..?

Comment: Which third party service or database you are using?

Comment: If you have the skills look into the logs of mysql and see if the is an error that can be fixed, or contact the support

Comment: Im using MYSQL database

Comment: If you have control over the MySQL system then increase the "max_allowed_packet" value on the server. like mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=value;

Comment: Please share the error from the log (storage/logs/laravel.log).